# Python + Arduino Make auto code generation but not working

Tags: python, svg, arduino

My Problem is I have a syntax error in python in the line 21 (see code(http://pastebin.com/ZqZ2ywSD)) maked by the function "file.write()".

The programm reads from a svg file that exists!
And writes in two files "loop.txt" and "setup.txt" for the code to arduino (files exists too).

But I can't find the problem...

More Details:

I need the code for my TFT Touch Display

I have created an svg file and I want to convert it to a gui for an Arduino TFT Display.

Code: (http://pastebin.com/ZqZ2ywSD)

Comment: Your program is full of syntax errors. I'm afraid there's too many to go through. I think you need to read a book on python first.

Comment: The [auto] tag is specific to C++11 and does not apply her and has been removed. Please be mindful of how you tag your questions in the future.